# Check for mandatory tag keys and values

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I am new with rego and I am finding it difficult to get my head around on how to write a policy. Based on information on the internet, I tried to write a policy to ensure that required tag keys and its values are present in the 'input' tfplan (terraform plan) . Using the code below, I can check if the required tag key are present in the input JSON, however I am not sure how to match values for this key.

Below is the input data for example (not putting the complete tfplan here):

```json
"tags_all": {
    "application": "app_name",
    "billingcode": "12345",
    "contact": "email_id",
    "dept": "101",
    "div": "22",
    "domain": "data",
    **"env": "dev"**,
    "initiator": "some_name",
    **"project": "abc"**
}
```

Below is the code

```
package tfplan

# The format to store required tags can be CHANGED, if needed
required_tags := {"tags": [
    {"tagkey": "project", "tagvalue": ["abc","def"]},
    {"tagkey": "env", "tagvalue": ["stage","prod"]},
]}

array_contains(arr, elem) {
    arr[_] == elem
}

deny[reason] {
    # reading tags from terraform plan
    resource := input.resource_changes[_]
    tags := resource.change.after.tags_all
    existing_tags_keys := [ key | tags[key] ]
    
    required_tag := required_tags.tags[_]
    required_tag_key := required_tag.tagkey
    required_tag_value := required_tag.tagvalue
    not array_contains(existing_tags_keys, required_tag_key)
    
    reason := sprintf(
        "%s: missing required key %q and value %q",
        [resource.address, required_tag_key, required_tag_value]
    )  

}
```

My expectation is that "env" and "project" from tags_all (input) should match the required_tags's key and the value for the matching key should exist in the list of values in required tags.

Can some one guide me on how to write this?

Question 2] In the above current code, if the Key matches, i see empty values in the result something like this:

```json
{   "result": [
    {
      "expressions": [
        {
          "value": [],
          "text": "data.tfplan.deny",
          "location": {
            "row": 1,
            "col": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }   ] }
```

How can I update the deny function to just return True or False in case of matching policy.